# Does Mono support "Module Initializers"?

Tags: .net, mono

Just curious if mono has support for "Module Initializers"?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

I don't know IL, but I wrote this in C#

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
    }  
}
```

I then used monodis to generate the il file and I added this code after the .module main.exe line.

```
.method assembly specialname rtspecialname static
  void .cctor() cil managed
{
   .maxstack 8
   IL_0000:  ldstr "module method"
   IL_0005:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
   IL_000a:  ret
}
```

And when it runs I get the output expected.

```
module method
Main
```

Both ilasm and the runtime supports it.

Comment: +1 I was almost going to say "nice to see on SO", until I realised you were one of the most inactive 3-year-old members around. :-P

Comment: Yeah. But good answer anyway! Especially considering Simon is something of an IL guru, in some people's minds. ;-)