# Does MonoTouch support Module Initializers?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cil, il

Just curious if MonoTouch has support for "Module Initializers"?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx

Related question: [Does Mono support "Module Initializers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974726/does-mono-support-module-initializers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first link answer, at least half, your own question. The Mono runtime supports **Module Initializers** and the test done (to prove this) was executed with Mono's JIT.

MonoTouch uses the JIT when executing on the iOS simulator, so there's no reason why it would not work there.

It likely works (or it's a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com)) for devices too, i.e. where the AOT compiler is being used. As Jason said, it's a matter of testing it. If you cannot test it yourself simply fill a bug report and attach a (self-contained) test case to it and we'll confirm if it works (or keep the bug open until it does).

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN article you linked to

> Since C# does not support global functions, C# does not support module
>   initializer.

Comment: correct. c# does not support module initialisers. but .net does. so c# can consume an assembly that uses them. and you can inject them into into a c# assembly. I leverage them in this  https://github.com/SimonCropp/ModuleInit and this https://github.com/SimonCropp/Costura. Also since MonoTouch "converts IL to IOS binary" and module initialisers are an IL feature it should work.

Comment: Possibly.  Easiest way to find out would be to test it.